# Compare two columns from two related tables using scopes in Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm trying to create a scope that will compare two columns on two related tables.

Based on these tables I would like to be able to get all instances of the `ServiceCall` model where the `next_service_date` is within the next 15 days, where the `Customer` model either has a `null` value for the `last_contact_date` or where it's before the `ServiceCall`'s `next_service_date`.

Relevant table structure:

**customers**

- id
- last_contact_date

**service_calls**

- id
- customer_id
- next_service_date

Working SQL for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```sql
SELECT service_calls.next_service_date, customers.last_contact_date FROM service_calls 
INNER JOIN customers ON service_calls.customer_id = customers.id
WHERE service_calls.next_service_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
AND (customers.last_contact_date < service_calls.next_service_date OR customers.last_contact_date IS NULL);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this part of the SQL `customers.last_contact_date < service_calls.next_service_date` with scopes?

This is what I have so far which does everything except the above.

Customer model:

```php
public function scopeNotContacted(Builder $builder): Builder
{
    return $builder->whereNull('last_contact_date');
}
```

ServiceCall model:

```php
public function scopeUpcoming(Builder $builder): Builder
{
    return $builder->whereBetween('next_service_date', [
        Carbon::today(),
        Carbon::today()->addDays(15)
    ])->whereHas('customer', fn ($builder) => $builder->notContacted());
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using an additional package [kirschbaum-development/eloquent-power-joins](https://github.com/kirschbaum-development/eloquent-power-joins)

I removed the scope from the `Customer` model

ServiceCall model:

```php
public function scopeNotContacted($builder)
{
    $builder->joinRelationship('customers', function ($join) {
        $join->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('customers.last_contact_date')
                  ->orWhereRaw('customers.last_contact_date < service_calls.next_service_date');
        });
    });
}

public function scopeUpcoming($builder)
{
    $builder->whereBetween('next_service_date', [
        Carbon::today(),
        Carbon::today()->addDays(15)
    ])->notContacted();
}
```